# java regex mask all elements in a list with last 4 characters visible

Tags: java, regex, masking

I have a list of alphanumeric strings as below

```
["nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN"]
```

I need to mask all elements with last 4 characters visible and [ " must not be masked as below.

```
["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4y74","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXdeNv","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX12NN"]
```

I have tried using

```
(\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)
```

as the key and $1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9 as the value in

```
maskedValue = maskedValue.replaceAll("(\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)", "$1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9")
```

but this only masked the first element.

```
["XXXXXXXXXXdeNv","nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74"]
```

Any leads are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could match a word char asserting 4 word chars at the end of the string `\w(?=\w*\w{4}$)` and replace with `X` https://regex101.com/r/xY73eY/1

Comment: Hi Paul

Thanks for the info. I have already tried this. Problem here is, the above regex only matched a single element.

String input = "[\"nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74\",\"GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv\",\"GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN\"]";
boolean valid = input.matches("\\w(?=\\w*\\w{4}$)");

this returns false as it is not matching the list of elements.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: All the suggestions mentioned work if I have to mask using my own implementation. Here I am bound to use a third party defined way by passing just a key which is a regex that matches my string ((\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)) and a format which species they way it should be masked ($1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9). I need a way similar to below line of code.
maskedValue = maskedValue.replaceAll("(\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)", "$1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9");

Answer (score 2):

For a single value, you could use an assertion to match a word character asserting 4 characters at the end of the string.

```
\w(?=\w*\w{4}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i64BDA/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/2h8p4K)

```
String values[] = {"nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN"};
for (String element : values)
    System.out.println(element.replaceAll("\\w(?=\\w*\\w{4}$)", "X"));
```

Output

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4y74
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXdeNv
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX12NN
```

---

For the whole string, you might use a finite quantifier in a positive lookbehind to match the opening `"` followed by a number of word characters. Then match all the characters that have 4 character before the closing `"`

```
"(?<=\"{0,100})\\w(?=\\w*\\w{4}\")"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHw1C6/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/nSwGhl)

```
String regex = "(?<=\"{0,100})\\w(?=\\w*\\w{4}\")";
String string = "[\"nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74\",\"GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv\",\"GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN\"] ";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(regex, "X"));
```

Output

```
["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4y74","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXdeNv","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX12NN"]
```

Comment: The entire ["nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN"] is part of a json response and should be considered as a single string. I am not supposed to tokenize or split this string with [ " list of elements " ]

Comment: @RamaKrishnaRajuGVSS Parsing it as json would be better, but I have added another option to get mask all except the last 4 characters.

Comment: All the suggestions mentioned work if I have to mask using my own implementation. Here I am bound to use a third party defined way by passing just a key which is a regex that matches my string ((\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)) and a format which species they way it should be masked ($1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9). I need a way similar to below line of code.
maskedValue = maskedValue.replaceAll("(\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)", "$1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9");

Answer (score 1):

Using a stream:

```java
List<String> terms = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74",
    "GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv",
    "GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN"
});
List<String> termsOut = terms.stream()
    .map(t -> String.join("", Collections.nCopies(t.length() - 4, "x")) +
              t.substring(t.length() - 4))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(termsOut);
```

This prints:

```
[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4y74,
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdeNv, 
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12NN]
```

Note that this solution does not even use regex, which means it may outperform a regex based solution.

Comment: The entire ["nG5wnyPVNxS6PbbDNNbRsK5zanG94Et6Q4y74","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1odeNv","GgQoDWqP7KtxXeePyyebu5EnNp8XxPC1o12NN"] is part of a json response and should be considered as a single string and I am only permitted to use replaceAll.

Comment: Then parse the JSON array into a Java collection.  I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I totally agree with your comments however the masking in my case is being taken care through 
 a third party jar to which I am supposed to pass properties as below

key:\\"accountIdList\\"[\\s]*\\:[\\s]*(\\W+)(\\W+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\W+)
mask:\\"accountIdList\\":$1$2XXXXXXXXXX$4$5$6$7$8$9

Masking in third party jar will be taken care by these properties using java replaceAll method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of these strings will start and end with quotes

**Algo:**

Use a flag or stack data structure to know if it's a starting quote or ending quote.
For example:
Traverse the string. Initially flag will be false. When you encounter a new quote you have to flip flag and keep traversing till you find other quote. You can do the same with
Stack stack = new Stack<>();

Sample workflow:

```
String str="random";
    
boolean flag = false;
int idx = 0;
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> indices = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(); // for final string
int start;
int end;
    
while(idx < str.length()){
    
    if (str.charAt(idx) == '"' && !flag){
    // start index of string
    string.append(s.charAt(idx));
    start = idx;
    flag = true;
    }
    
    else if (str.charAt(idx) == '"' && !flag){
    // end index of string
    flag = false;
    end = idx;
char[] mask = new char[end-3-start];
Arrays.fill(mask, 'x');
    string.append(new String(mask)); // need to put 'x' in place
    }
    
    if (!flag){
    string.append(s.charAt(idx));
    }
    
    idx++;
}
```

Complexity: O(n)