# Java regex mask all elements in a specific list in string

Tags: java, json, regex, masking, data-masking

I have a string converted from JSON object.

```
  String myString =   { 
      \"name\":\"Dennis", 
      \"password\":\"12345\",
      \"secretValue\":\"12345\",
      \"OtherSecretList\":[\"ADD\",\"BND\"],
      \"TypeList\":[\"M\",\"F\"] 
    }
```

I want to mask some values before logging.

```
String result = myString.replaceAll("(?<=secretValue\":\")(.*?)(?=\")", "*****")
                        .replaceAll("(?<=password\":\")(.*?)(?=\")", "*****");
```

This works for non-array values. But I want to mask OtherSecretList elements, too.

I tried this answer

[java regex mask all elements in a list with last 4 characters visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751285/java-regex-mask-all-elements-in-a-list-with-last-4-characters-visible)

I want to see value like

```
OtherSecretList:["****","****"]
```

But failed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The easiest thing to do here is to parse your raw JSON string using something like GSON, mask what you want, then convert back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at this regex. https://regex101.com/r/WdWpgx/3

Notice that this solution only works when json file is smaller than 10000. Since java lookbehind does not support full regex, it only allow limited size.

```
(?<=OtherSecretList\":\[.{0,10000}?\") # Match the secret list position. And assume that they are in the same line. Then match their own quote position.
(\w*(?=\w{4}\")|[A-Z]*(?=\w*\")) # If character longer than 4, then match as much as possible until only four left; otherwise, mask all to the another double quotation.
```